# Android: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord when SAMPLERATE set to 44100 with supported phone

Tags: android, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I get an error, when I set the sampling rate to 44100 for the AudioRecord object. When it's 22050 it works fine.

The Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
```

I also tried this function to see if my phone(lg l50) is supported and according to this function my phone is supported. I get the log entry for all supported rates.

```
public void getValidSampleRates() {
        for (int rate : new int[] {8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100}) {  // add the rates you wish to check against
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            if (bufferSize > 0) {
                // buffer size is valid, Sample rate supported
                Log.d("SEBA", "valid sample rate" + rate);
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT3:** Code for the entire program & changed the code to be more robust & code works for all sample rates

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100; //8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, (44100??) works
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;
int bufferSize;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);

    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

    getValidSampleRates();
}

private void setButtonHandlers() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
    ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}

private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
    enableButton(R.id.btnStart, !isRecording);
    enableButton(R.id.btnStop, isRecording);
}

int BufferElements2Rec = 1024; // want to play 2048 (2K) since 2 bytes we use only 1024
int BytesPerElement = 2; // 2 bytes in 16bit format

private void startRecording() {

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, 
bufferSize*1); 
// Multiply by 1 or 2 or 3 in order this code to work for all sample rates

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;
    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            writeAudioDataToFile();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
}

//convert short to byte
private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
    int shortArrsize = sData.length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
        bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
        bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
        sData[i] = 0;
    }
    return bytes;

}

private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    // Write the output audio in byte
//        String filePath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/wav_voice"+RECORDER_SAMPLERATE+"16bitmono.pcm";
    String filePath = "/sdcard/voice8K16bitmono.pcm";
    Log.d("SEBA", "path: " + filePath);
    short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];

    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (isRecording) {
        // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format

        recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
        System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
        try {
            // // writes the data to file from buffer
            // // stores the voice buffer
            byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
            os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    // stops the recording activity
    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }
}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnStart: {
                enableButtons(true);
                startRecording();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.btnStop: {
                enableButtons(false);
                stopRecording();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void getValidSampleRates() {
    for (int rate : new int[] {8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100}) {  // add the rates you wish to check against
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        if (bufferSize > 0) {
            // buffer size is valid, Sample rate supported
            Log.d("SEBA", "valid sample rate" + rate);
        }
    }
}
```

}

And If I use CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT or CHANNEL_OUT_DEFAULT instead of deprecated AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT I get same results.(Device supports all rates)

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you set up the recorder. Also, `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Why are you using `BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement` as the buffer size when creating the `AudioRecord` instead of the value returned from `getMinBufferSize`?

Comment: @Michael I replaced BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement with BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement * 2 and now it works, thanx

Comment: That still doesn't sound very robust. You should call `getMinBufferSize` and use a buffer size greater than or equal to the value it returns.

Comment: @Michael Now This code if I use other sample rates other than 44100 sound not correct. This code doesn't work for sample rates other than 44100.

Comment: @Michael I figured out what was wrong. bufferSize needs to be multiplied by a factor 1, 2 or 3 for the code to work for all sample rates, see code.